# 7zip latest version pragmatically?

Tags: windows, vb.net, 7zip

I want to compare 7zip.exe version installed on client machine with the latest version released.

At present, I am able to fetch the latest version number by downloading source code from page URL https://www.7-zip.org/download.html .

Here is my code. **Is there any API (Seems there is no API available)/ other better solution to read 7zip latest version programmatically?**

```
Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.7-zip.org/download.html")
```

Comment: You can find the download links of versions in `https://www.7-zip.org/download.html` by finding html tags. There are many library which make this. Get HTML string and find the links. It will help you. Cause, there is no API to get that link or version strings. Or you can save the 7zip file to your server and then users can download it.

Comment: You can run the 7z.exe from your code without parameters and redirect the output to a text file. Parse that file to get the version. Try running it from command prompt to check. `"%programfiles%"\7-zip\7z.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it, but it's susceptible to changes

```
Private Function GetInstalledVersion() As Single
    Dim version As Single = Nothing
    Using root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
        Using key = root.OpenSubKey("Software\7-Zip", False)
            Dim appPath As String = CStr(key.GetValue("Path"))
            Dim appVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(appPath, "7z.exe"))
            If Not Single.TryParse(appVersion.ProductVersion, version) Then
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to retrieve installed version")
            End If
            Return version
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Private Function GetWebVersion() As Single
    Dim r As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Download 7-Zip ).*?(?= )")
    Dim web = New Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.7-zip.org/download.html")
    Dim version As Single = Nothing
    If Not Single.TryParse(r.Match(web).Value, version) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to retrieve web version")
    End If
    Return version
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer of *Innat3*, this is susceptible to changes. But this is working fine for now.

So, here is a version using PHP and regex:

```php
<?php

echo "Getting the latest version of 7-Zip..." . PHP_EOL;
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.7-zip.org/download.html');
$regex = '/<P><B>Download 7-Zip ([0-9a-zA-Z\.]+) \([0-9-]+\)<\/B>:<\/P>/';
preg_match($regex, $html, $matches);

if (!isset($matches[1])) {
    echo 'Could not get the latest version of 7-Zip.' . PHP_EOL;
    return;
}
$version = str_replace(".", "", $matches[1]);
echo "Latest Z-Zip version: $version" . PHP_EOL;
```

*Seems like PHP still exists in 2023...*